# How to release memory of vector of CvMat pointers?

Tags: c++, opencv

I created a vector of CvMat pointer as follows:

```
vector<CvMat*> items;
for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){
  CvMat* mat = cvCreateMat(5,1,CV_32FC1);
  // assign values to mat
  items.push_back(mat);
}
```

And then I tried to release memory as follows:

```
for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){
  cvReleaseMat(&items[i]);
}
vector<CvMat*>().swap(items);
```

However, I don't see that affected the memory usage in Task Manager.

Any ideas for me?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: that's just 25 floats plus 5 matrix headers, so it is probably not enough to appear in the Task Manager

Comment: This is just example and it is up to 10MB memory in the real application...

Answer (score 2):

The memory is not returned to the system.

In most runtime environments memory allocated to an application from the operating system remains in the application, and is seldom returned back to the operating system. Freeing a memory block allows you to reuse the block from within the application, but does not free it to the operating system to make it available to other applications.

UPD:

So anyway Task Manager can't be reliable tool for controlling memory allocations and deallocations. If you want to guarantee that your application does not have memory leaks you may want to use such tools as valgrind (if you are on Linux), or drMemory from google, or several others (google for "memory leak detection"). In this case you will have the most precise information about allocations, deallocations, leaks, memory access violations etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help, nogard! But when I call cvReleaseMat for a single CvMat*, I see memory changes in the TaskManager. That is really strange...